# WIX Windows 8.1 Pin to Start Screen

Tags: wix

I need some help with getting my WIX installer to place a shortcut as a tile in the Windows 8.1 Start Screen.

So far I have tried the following code (just extending the start menu shortcut to experiment) which is not adding it to the Start Screen:

```
<Component Id="SomeStartMenuShortcut" Guid="{E06506E8-21F7-421C-8088-3810E0DC04D2}">
    <Condition>INSTALLSTARTMENUSHORTCUT</Condition>
    <Shortcut Id="SomeStartMenuShortcut" Name="SomeApp" Target="[INSTALL]SomeApp.exe" WorkingDirectory="INSTALL">
      <ShortcutProperty Key="System.AppUserModel.ID" Value="SomeApp.exe" />
      <ShortcutProperty Key="{9F4C2855-9F79-4B39-A8D0-E1D42DE1D5F3}, 12" Value="2" />
    </Shortcut>
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\SomeCompany\SomeApp" Name="StartMenuShortcut" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>        
    <RemoveFolder Id="SomeStartMenuShortcut" On="uninstall"/>
</Component>
```

From the following research:

http://wyrdfish.wordpress.com/2013/02/05/shortcuts-as-tiles-on-windows-8/
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2009/09/02/windows-7-taskbar-support-with-the-msishortcutproperty-table.aspx

Although I am now beginning to suspect that this may only be responsible for allowing a shortcut to display Pin to Start & Pin to Taskbar as options on its context menu...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pin to start menu.  Only windows or the user can.  You only can decide what shortcuts NOT to display on the start menu.

I remember in one of building windows 8 blog posts they said it's this way to prevent "spamming" of the start menu."

Comment: Ah that's a shame. I wonder if there might be a way round this with custom actions... Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I fundamentally don't understand this concept of "spamming".  Since when is the operating system responsible for third party software being irritating?  My installer has no trouble putting a shortcut on the desktop.
Whenever I install something which creates 3 system tray icons, constant update pop-ups, requests to restart, etc.,  I wholly blame the developers of that package;  I don't begrudge the OS for allowing it do that.
"I disapprove of what your installer does, but I will defend to the death its right to do it."